# pry raise an error using show-models with neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I just switched rails console to use pry.

I'm also using ruby 2.1.2p95, rails 4.1.5, neo4j (3.0.0.alpha.11), neo4j-community (2.1.3), neo4j-core (3.0.0.alpha.19)

While executing the command show-models it failed, returning the following error:

[3] pry(main)> show-models
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)
from /home/pdipietro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/neo4j-2e41203410cc/lib/neo4j/active_node/has_n.rb:79:in `has_one'

has anyone an idea on how to circunvent it?

Thank you

Paolo

Answer (score 2):

Look in your models, one of them has a bad `has_one` call. Every `has_one` requires at minimum two parameters: a direction and an association name. That indicates you have one that's probably using the old syntax, just doing `has_one :association`. See documentation at https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Declared-Relationships.

EDIT: Unfortunately, I just tested and it doesn't look like `show-models` doesn't recognize these models. You can add an issue at https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j and we can work on adding support. The error you're reporting still has nothing to do with pry, though.

Also, 3.0.0.alpha.11 is quite old at this point, the gem has been released and is now up to 3.0.1. You should really update.